# how to use the lowercase in linq using C# mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I am trying to Create the linq query using lowercase that time its getting error in C# MongoDB
That the error looks like
{document}{Queue}.ToString().ToLower() is not supported.

Here is my Code

```
(from c in Collection.AsQueryable()
 where c["Projects"]["_id"] == ProjectId && c["Name"].ToString().ToLower() == Name.ToLower
 select c).ToList();
```

Thanks,
Pari`

Answer (score 1):

This because `IQueryProvider` does not recognise how to deal with chained methods try  to drop `ToString()` 
Or use the follwing syntax because is implementend and interpreted in the mongodriver 
something like the following

```
MongoCollection.FindAsync(c=>c.Name.ToLower()==name.ToLower())
```

I'm sure this should work because if you take a look at [`PredicateTranslate.cs`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/21e8768c964b37ed9f8b0039efdadff71fc465b3/src/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/Translators/PredicateTranslator.cs) of mongodriver you will find the methods that mongo can interpret

Comment: so  share it if it's different from one of what's proposed  or mark ione as an answer  this the goal of stackoverlflow

Answer (score 0):

This is all from a vague recollection of a problem I had years ago, and I haven't been able to verify any of this, but...   ...I think this might work.

```
(from c in Collection.AsQueryable()
where where c["Projects"]["_id"] == ProjectId
    && c["Name"].Equals(Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
select c).ToList();
```

I think this query ensures the name case check is happening client-side. I believe your original query is asking MongoDB to do the case checking, but the query parser has no idea how to convert C# constructs like ToLower().

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that this will be hideously inefficient to do client-side since you'll have to pull all of the results back, especially if you expect to deal with a lot of records. I had a similar situation, but thankfully it was login e-mail addresses so I just inserted them all lowercase :) 
Hmm, it looks like Mongo have text indexes with some degree of case insensitivity now:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#text-index-case-insensitivity

Comment: @john Would the filtering by project id kick in first and restrict the result set somewhat?

Comment: Yes, it would, so in this case it should be fine. I missed that the collection was "Projects" so assumed that there could be multiple "Project Id" references. My bad. The case insensitive text indexes do look interesting, however! :)

Comment: Indeed they do, hence the upvote on your comment! Cheers.

Comment: What's the point of calling `ToLower` in conjunction with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`?  That option specifies a case insensitive comparison, so calling `ToLower` seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway. Yep, good spot. I missed it in the copy and paste. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its will not be working.. Please give me a good solution..

Comment: @user2979432 Can you post your solution here so others will know what it is if they hit the same problem? Thanks.